# How to set Button panel at the top of the window in JFrame?

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton

In my mini browser program my buttonPanel contains backButton, forwardButton and locationTextField. fPane contains buttonPanel and jfxPanel. The browser window should be look like the buttonPanel on the top and the other things cover the rest of the window.

Here is my constructor portion:

```
private JButton backButton = new JButton(), forwardButton = new JButton();

private final JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();

private JTextField locationTextField = new JTextField(40);

private JPanel fPane = new JPanel();

public Browser(){
createScene();
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024,600));
setResizable(true);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5,0));
buttonPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3, 5, 3, 5));
buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
backButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Hello.class.getResource("/left.png")));
backButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
buttonPanel.add(backButton,BorderLayout.NORTH);
forwardButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Hello.class.getResource("/forward.png")));
forwardButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
buttonPanel.add(forwardButton,BorderLayout.NORTH);
buttonPanel.add(locationTextField,BorderLayout.CENTER);
fPane.add(buttonPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
fPane.add(jfxPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(5,0));
getContentPane().add(fPane, BorderLayout.WEST);
pack();
}
```

When i compile it,it looks like this:

[image]

the buttonPanel goes aside instead of going top of the window, back button disappears and extra space is created below the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed the buttons are placed inside `buttonPanel`, then you might try

```
getContentPane().add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
getContentPane().add(fPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

before the `pack()`

Comment: but extra space under and both side of the screen doesn't disappear